# Mongoose find (findOne) from a reference subDocument property array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

So, I'm trying to use the poulate and match property but without any success, I couldn't find any documentation of my problem (I struggled to find a documentation about it too, so maybe you can provide me some source other then [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions))?)

Btw, I have this two models:

1 - **Pages**

```
const PageSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    organization: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'organizations',
    }, 
})
```

1 - **Organizations**

```
const OrganizationSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    domains: [{
        type: String,
        unique: true
    }],
})
```

I need to find the page that belongs to a specific domain, so I was doing this findOne Query:

```
const page = await  Page.findOne({ 
    'settings.slug':  req.params.slug
}).populate({
    path: 'organization',
    match: {domains:"foo.com"},
}).exec()
```

It doesn't make the "filter" and returns the pages that have an organization without the domain "foo.com"

I tried an even more easy approach but it doesn't work neither:

```
const presentation = await  Page.findOne({ 
    'organization.domains': host,
    'settings.slug':  req.params.slug
}).populate('organization')
```

It returns always null.

Can someone help me? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this line

```
.populate({
    path: 'organization',  <---  you forgot an s //organizations as declared in you ref
```

Comment: Mhhhhh i don't think so, the name inside the PageSchema is "organization"

Comment: can you try it and see if it works, also can you check your DB  if the _id in your PageSchema are the same in Organizations